# Getting value from a pair fails with: TYPENAME does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, std-pair

Here is what i want to do. I want to store de data from a Http response, headers and data. I figured an easy way to do this would be to store the response and the data as a pair. The data is fetched from a LRU-cache. The LRU cache takes a key(string) and the pair. The HTTPResponse is in the form of a POCO C++ HTTPResponse object. But i cant get the string from the second argument of the pair!

```
        this->clientCache = new LRUPersistentCache<string, pair<HTTPResponse, string > >(3,cachePath);



    pair<HTTPResponse,string> tmp = (*this->clientCache->get(headKey));// Get the pair
    cout << ((string*)tmp.second()).c_str();  //Should get the second object of the pair!
// But gives: Type std::basic_string<char> does not provide a call operator.
```

Writing it like below gives the same error:

```
            cout << (*this->clientCache->get(headKey)).second().c_str();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << ((string*)tmp.second()).c_str(); 
                ^^
```

you are casting to a `string*`. It should be just `string` (or nothing at all) because the `second` of `pair<HTTPResponse,string>` is just a `string`.

and second is a just member not a member function so it should be `tmp.second`

---

```
cout << tmp.second.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

`second` is a memeber value not function defined in standard as

## 20.3.2 Class template pair

> namespace std {
>     template 
>     struct pair {
>       typedef T1 first_type;
>       typedef T2 second_type;
>       T1 first;
>       T2 second;

thus correct usage of second member value is `second` not `second()`. Unless it is functor you are going to use, which is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

To access the elements of a pair, you need:

```
pair_object.first
// or
pair_object.second
```

Those are plain member variables, not accessor functions. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair